# lightGBM predicts same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have one problem concerning lgb. When I write

```
lgb.train(.......)
```

it finishes in less than milisecond. (for (10 000,25) ) shape dataset.

and when I write predict, all the output variables have same value.

```
train = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv', dtype = dtypes)
test = pd.read_csv('data/test.csv')

test.head()

X = train.iloc[:10000, 3:-1].values
y = train.iloc[:10000, -1].values

sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)

#pca = PCA(0.95)
#X = pca.fit_transform(X)

d_train = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)
params = {}
params['learning_rate'] = 0.003
params['boosting_type'] = 'gbdt'
params['objective'] = 'binary'
params['metric'] = 'binary_logloss'
params['sub_feature'] = 0.5
params['num_leaves'] = 10
params['min_data'] = 50
params['max_depth'] = 10

num_round = 10
clf = lgb.train(params, d_train, num_round, verbose_eval=1000)

X_test = sc.transform(test.iloc[:100,3:].values)

pred = clf.predict(X_test,  num_iteration = clf.best_iteration)
```

when I print pred, all the values are (0.49)

It's my first time using **lightgbm** module. Do I have some error in the code? or I should look for some mismatches in dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **num_round** is too small, it just starts to learn and stops there. Other than that, make your verbose_eval smaller, so see the results visually upon training. My suggestion for you to try the lgb.train code as below:

**clf = lgb.train(params, d_train, num_boost_round=5000, verbose_eval=10, early_stopping_rounds = 3500)**

Always use **early_stopping_rounds** since the model should stop if there is no evident learning or the model starts to overfit.

Do not hesitate to ask more. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am trying that approach. For early stopping it required validation set. I managed to add that but now I receive error 
TypeError: train() got multiple values for argument 'num_boost_round'
I am trying to solve it for now.

Comment: 'num_boost_round' should be the same with 'num_round', that may be the cause of your error. Here is a piece from one of my codes for the validation set problem of yours:  myLGB = lgb.train(params,
                   d_train,
                   valid_sets=[d_train, d_test],
                   num_boost_round=4000,
                   verbose_eval=10,
                   early_stopping_rounds = 2750)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes it was my error and I corrected it. Thanks a lot.